# Batch expert needed file cannot be for looped because of first symbol

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having a bit of an issue in the link there is a text file and you will notice that first character is unknown symbol and after batch tries to for loop it only copies that first character and stops there.

Is there a way to tell batch to continue or to warn him before that there is unknown symbol? or even delete it and proceed with the rest of file?

Link to text file:
https://easyupload.io/eknrri

Script:

```
:: Turn echo off
@echo off

:: Enable extensions
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Set input file
set "InputFile=index.txt"

:: Set output file
set "OutputFile=output.txt"

:: Check if output file exits if it does delete it
If Exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%"

:: Loop through input file
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
    :: Set line equal to file text
    set line=%%A

    echo !line!
)>>"%OutputFile%"
```

Why does this `powershell -command Get-Content -encoding UTF8 "%InputFile%" > test.txt` not set file to plain text file, but manually save as works?

Comment: The file is a binary one. [`hexdump.exe`](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/hexdump-for-windows.html) shows first six bytes `07 00 21 00 00 00`. Unfortunately, `type` requires plain text files…

Comment: Is there a way to convert it with batch? please anything and thank you for your comment it's helping me a lot. The file can be copied and modified it doesn't matter, first symbol can be removed it just needs to be in a batch. Or is there a way to something else than type? because setting just "%InputFile%" doesn't give anything back.

Comment: Is it possbile with running powershell command inside batch file? and modifying first symbol to be read by batch?

Comment: Where this _binary_ file comes from?  It could be readable using a utility shipped with the app which generated it?

Comment: It's a custom program and I know it can be easly avoided with any other language, but I don't have any other options, but to use batch...is there really no way? I don't get why manually going to save as does the trick, but batch can't

Comment: @JosefZ thank you for all your help and your findings. I'm grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm having a bit of an issue in the link there is a text file

Unfortunately the file you have linked to is **not** a text file:

```
$ file index.txt
index.txt: Targa image data - Color 65536 x 65536 x 0 ""
```

It is an image file ([Truevision TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA)) according to the header information in the file. It is also damaged or truncated.

> Truevision TGA, often referred to as TARGA, is a raster graphics file format created by Truevision Inc. (now part of Avid Technology). It was the native format of TARGA and VISTA boards, which were the first graphic cards for IBM-compatible PCs to support Highcolor/truecolor display.

---

> after batch tries to for loop it only copies that first character and stops there

`For` loops (together with `type`) are used for processing text files, not binary files like images.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for everyone who gave it a shot. Much appreciated guys.